# Get all CSS classes into an array and make a calculation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to placed an exchange rate in text field and update multiple text area rates need to be update

```
Exchange Rate <input type="text" value="" id="exchange_rate">
<input type="button" value="Update Price" id="update_price">
```

text area counts are dynamic, here some sample

```
<input class="price" name="pro_name[88197][1]" rel="4450000" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[12316][2]"  rel="4451000" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[46511][3]" rel="4575120" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[45151][4]" rel="2343400" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[165652][5]" rel="4534500" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[85559][6]" rel="4450000" value=""  type="text">
```

Now I need to bring above each text area value want to be 
rel * exchange_rate = value
(rel is japan YEN amount, exchange rate is USD)

and I start my jquery like this and stuck, Please help me someone!!

```
$("#update_price").click(function () {
   var all_price_element = [];
   price_class = $( ".price" ).toArray();

   for ( var i = 0; i < price_class.length; i++ ) {
     all_price_element.push( price_class[ i ].innerHTML );
   }

});
```

Comment: I passed the rel as Japan YEN currency amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

So the snippet is:

```js
$("#update_price").click(function (e) {
  //
  // get the current exchange_rate and convert it to number
  //
  var er = +document.getElementById('exchange_rate').value;

  
  //
  // for each price element do the calculation:
  //
  // get the current rel value, convert it to number and
  // multiply per rel
  //
  $( ".price").each(function(index, element) {
    element.value = er * +element.getAttribute('rel');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  Exchange Rate <input type="text" value="" id="exchange_rate">
<input type="button" value="Update Price" id="update_price">

<input class="price" name="pro_name[88197][1]" rel="4450000" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[12316][2]"  rel="4451000" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[46511][3]" rel="4575120" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[45151][4]" rel="2343400" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[165652][5]" rel="4534500" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[85559][6]" rel="4450000" value=""  type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update all price like following.

```js
$("#update_price").click(function () {  
    var ex_rate = $('#exchange_rate').val();   
  
    $(".price").each(function() {
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel')
        $(this).val(ex_rate * rel);
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price" name="pro_name[88197][1]" rel="4450000" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[12316][2]"  rel="4451000" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[46511][3]" rel="4575120" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[45151][4]" rel="2343400" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[165652][5]" rel="4534500" value=""  type="text">
<input class="price" name="pro_name[85559][6]" rel="4450000" value=""  type="text">

Exchange Rate
<input type="text" value="" id="exchange_rate">
<input type="button" value="Update Price" id="update_price">
```

Comment: rel is dynamic, we need to get it from the query, its not fixed